# Linking to my root domain

Tags: text, dns, anchor, root

After reading http://moz.com/blog/understanding-root-domains-subdomains-vs-subfolders-microsites, I am setting up links to my websit. I am a bit confused about linking to my root domain. If for example my anchor text is: "freelance website", to link this to my root domain on another website would the html look like this:

`<a href="http://www.treytrumble.com">freelance website</a>`

OR

`<a href="*.treytrumble.com">freelance website</a>`

Will the first one be counted as a root domain link even though it is a subdomain?

Comment: The first syntax is just fine.  Typically, "root domain" will refer to the hostname that your content is served from.  If it's served from www.treytrumble.com, then the link you gave is the "root" link.

Comment: The domain I bought was treytrumble.com and then later added the sub (www). Would my root then be http://treytrumble.com or just treytrumble.com?

Comment: The base domain (i.e. the thing you have control over) is treytrumble.com.  It is up to you whether you'd like to use that or the www form as the root of your website.  Maybe you can give a little more insight into your concerns?

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for helping me out with this. From the start:
1. I purchased treytrumble.com as my domain name.
2. I pointed treytrumble.com to www.treytrumble.com
3. I am now building links and want these external links from other websites to be directed at my root domain, which I think is http://treytrumble.com?

This article [link](http://moz.com/blog/understanding-root-domains-subdomains-vs-subfolders-microsites)  also has me a bit confused, because it shows the root domain beginning with (*.)

Comment: Yup, the "root domain" in that context for you is just treytrumble.com.  While Rand's suggestion is to use the root domain, my read on that is either the root domain or the www domain is fine, but be sure to use it for everything.  I.e. don't set up different domains for different purposes (with the exceptions that he lists).  And whatever you start with, whether treytrumble.com or www.tretrumble.com, stick with it.  My personal preference would be to just use treytrumble.com.

Answer (score 0):

Rand gives an example of a root domain as `*.seomoz.org`, but he really means to say that `seomoz.org` is the root domain.  So to link to it, do this:

```
<a href="http://treytrumble.com">freelance website</a>
```

Within the context of [his blog post](http://moz.com/blog/understanding-root-domains-subdomains-vs-subfolders-microsites) (and to my own personal knowledge) using `treytrumble.com` instead of `www.treytrumble.com` doesn't make a big difference, as long as you stick to just one choice.  Search engines do not relate unadorned domains to subdomains, nor give you any points (or subtract them) for one choice over another.